# Help with integral/logarithm inequality

Tags: limits, inequality, definite-integrals, logarithms

I have to prove the following inequality:

$1/(n+1) < \int_n^{n+1} 1/t$ $dt$ $<1/n$

I thought it would be easier to attack this via integration, so I get:

$1/(n+1) <$ log $(n+1)-$ log$(n)<1/n$

At this point I tried to use induction, but the solution is still not clear to me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Draw a picture. Our function $\frac{1}{t}$ is $\le \frac{1}{n}$ on our interval, and $\ge \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Yes, but how can I write this like a formal proof? Thanks again.

Comment: It depends how formal you want to be. For the Riemann integral, it is an early theorem that if $f(t)\le g(t)$ on the interval $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^bf(t)\,dt\le \int_a^b g(t)\,dt$. Usually we go in the other direction. We *prove* that $\frac{1}{n+1}\lt \log(n+1)-\log n\lt \frac{1}{n}$ by using the geometry.

Comment: Ok, so to apply this last criteria I should derivate $1/(n+1)$ and $1/n$ to get $-1/(n+1)^2$ and $-1/n^2$, which are below and above my function, then I can be conclusive about the integral, right?

Comment: I just realized I was wrong, both integrals are below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Draw a picture. On the interval $[n,n+1]$, our function $\frac{1}{t}$ is $\le \frac{1}{n}$, and $\ge \frac{1}{n+1}$.

So the area under the curve $\frac{1}{t}$, and above the $t$-axis, from $t=n$ to $t=n+1$, is *less than* the area of a rectangle with base $1$ and height $\frac{1}{n}$, and *greater than* the area of a rectangle with base $1$ and height $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

From the above geometric argument, it follows that
$\frac{1}{n+1}\lt \log(n+1)-\log n\lt \frac{1}{n}$.